# How to get the last months and years from current date

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create the JSON formatted as shown below, in decreasing order starting from current date (it will be the actual current date).

```
var theMonths = [
 {"date":"2015-12","value":null}, {"date":"2016-01","value":null},   
 {"date":"2016-02","value":null}, {"date":"2016-03","value":null},
 {"date":"2016-04","value":null}, {"date":"2016-05","value":null},
 {"date":"2016-06","value":null}, {"date":"2016-07","value":null},
 {"date":"2016-08","value":null}, {"date":"2016-09","value":null},
 {"date":"2016-10","value":null}, {"date":"2016-11","value":null},
 {"date":"2016-12","value":null}, {"date":"2017-01","value":null},
 {"date":"2017-02","value":null}, {"date":"2017-03","value":null},
 {"date":"2017-04","value":null}, {"date":"2017-05","value":null}
]
```

I want to pass this data in a chart.

Comment: What do you actually want to say? Elaborate it in more detail.

Comment: `theMonths = theMonths.reverse();`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I want to get the complete data dynamically from the date object and want to create the same array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass the last months till 1.5 years from current date in highchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795090/how-to-pass-the-last-months-till-1-5-years-from-current-date-in-highchart)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateFromPast = [];
```

var amountOfDatesFromPast = 18;
for (var i = 0; i < amountOfDatesFromPast; i++){

```
var dateObj = new Date();
dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth() - i);
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

newdate = year + "-" + month;
dateFromPast.push(newdate);
```

}
console.log(dateFromPast);